# Parsing XML Response after AJAX call in IE8

Tags: xml, ajax, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to parse an XML document returned from an AJAX call to a PHP script I've written. In Chrome, this works:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("line")[0].attributes.getNamedItem("pdfWidth").value
```

where

```
xmlDoc
```

is an object created from

```
parser.parseFromString(xmlhttp.responseText,"text/xml");
```

In IE,

```
xmlDoc
```

is created by:

```
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async="false";
xmlDoc.loadXML(xmlhttp.responseText);
```

However the above 'getElementsByTagName' returns undefined. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, can anyone assist?

**Edit - think I've sussed it, but I can't answer my own question apparently..**

I think I may have sussed this - the following seems to worK:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("line").item(0).getAttribute("pdfWidth");
```

Took me an hour that, grrrr IE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have sussed this - the following seems to worK:

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("line").item(0).getAttribute("pdfWidth");
```

Took me an hour that, grrrr IE!